# How to prove $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is strictly contained in $H^1(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is open and bounded?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

One why to do this is to show the orthogonal complement of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ is not $\{0\}$. Since   $H^1(\Omega)$ is the direct sum of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $(H^1_0(\Omega))^{\bot}$. But how to find a non-zero function in $(H^1_0(\Omega))^{\bot}$?

If $u\in (H^1_0(\Omega))^{\bot}$ then $u$ must satisfy $\Delta u=u$ in $\Omega$, but how to prove this P.D.E has non-zero solution in $H^1(\Omega)$ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you already know the Poincaré-Friedrichs-inequality, this is easy to establish. This inequality gives you a constant $C > 0$, such that
$$\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \le C \, \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$$
for all $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.
This inequality blatantly fails for the $H^1(\Omega)$ function which is constantly $1$.

Comment: Nice answer, it is much shorter then showing the claim directly with the definition.

Comment: Thanks for your very nice answer. But I want to write down a non-zero function  in $(H^1(\Omega))^{\bot}$ explicitly, without knowing the P-F inequality. Can we prove it just from the definition that $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C^{\infty}_0$ with respect to  the $H^1$ norm?

Comment: Then you can do the following: let $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$  be the orthogonal projection of $1$ onto $H_0^1(\Omega)$. Then, $v - 1 \in H_0^1(\Omega)^\perp$.

Comment: You are right. But this still relies on that $f(x)=1$ is not in $H^1_0(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\Omega$ is open and bounded then any constant function is trivially in $H^1(\Omega)$. By definition, $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with respect to the $H^1$-norm, so let's prove that $f(x) = 1$ cannot be approximated by compactly supported function.

> The idea is that in every compact subset of $\Omega$ we want our approximating sequence to be close to $1,$ but to enforce the fact the sequence has to be in $C_c^{\infty}$ we'll end up paying a lot on the gradient to drop quickly from $1$ to $0$ near the boundary of $\Omega$.

For simplicity, I'll work out the details for the case $N = 1$, $\Omega = (0,1)$, but the same technique can be applied for the general setting in which you phrased the question.

Let $\{\phi_n\} \subset C^{\infty}_c(0,1)$, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and assume by contradiction that $\|\phi_n - 1\|_{H^1} \le \epsilon$. Then in particular $\|\phi_n - 1\|_{L^2} \le \epsilon$, and if we let $A_n = \{x : \phi_n(x) \ge \frac 12\}$ we have that 
$$1 - \mathcal{L}^1(A_n) = \mathcal{L}^1(A_n^c)= \int_{A_n^c}2\cdot \frac 12dx \le \int_{A_n^c} 2 |1 - \phi_n|\le 2\epsilon.$$ This shows that $$\mathcal{L}^1(A_n) \ge 1 - 2\epsilon.$$
Let $y \in (0,3\epsilon)$ be such that $\phi_n(y) \ge \frac 12$ (the existence of such a $y$ is guaranteed by the estimate above). Then, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, we have \begin{align}
\frac 12 \le &\ \phi_n(y) - \phi_n(0) \le \int_0^{3\epsilon}|\phi_n'(x)|\,dx \le \sqrt{3\epsilon}\int_0^1|\phi'(x)|^2\,dx \\
= &\ \sqrt{3\epsilon}\|\nabla(\phi_n - 1)\|_{L^2} \le \sqrt{3\epsilon}\|\phi_n - 1\|_{H^1} \\
\le &\ \sqrt{3}\epsilon^{3/2}.
\end{align}

This gives a contradiction for $\epsilon$ small enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer. Roughly speaking, if constant function $f(x)=1$ can be approximated by sequence of $C^{\infty}_0$ functions, then near the boundary the approximating functions have to jump the gap between 1 an 0, so the gradient of the approximating sequence will change rapidly and this will destroy the continuity of gradient of the approximating functions.  Is this what you actually want to tell us?

Comment: @fengxiao: almost. what I'm saying is that you destroy the integrability of the gradients, not the continuity, although these concepts are actually closely related.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $\{e^{x_1}, e^{x_2}...\}$ and $\{e^{x_1+x_2}, e^{x_1+x_2+x_3}...\}$ are non-zero solutions to $\Delta u-u=0$.